# Openshift - Redirect requests only on specific gear

Tags: openshift, haproxy, openshift-gears

I'm using HAProxy and I have more than one gear, but I have to use file system.
The problem is Gears don't share file system so I wonder if I have to setup HAProxy in way to let me redirect specific requests to a specific gear(the one that contains cronjobs).

Must I use HAProxy or have I alternatives?

## Edit

Share the file system across gears would be great but not is completely  necessary. My users don't need access. I just want the posibility to write files in the same gear. My using an specific URL o any other trick.
For example, it would be enough an specific URL go always to an specific(and why not the same) gear.

Comment: What are you using the file system for exactly? You really shouldn't use the file system with scaled applications. You should use something like S3 or Dropbox instead.

Comment: @mbaird I use it for schedule cron jobs. The thing is I want avoid migrate to other PAAS. I see 2 options, redirect specifics requests OR stop using scale setup and return to non scale setup.

Comment: you can use something like Amazon S3 in conjunction with OpenShift. There is no reason to switch to a different PaaS. Perhaps if you provided details as to what you are doing that uses the file system I could help more. Are you using the Cron cartridge provided by OpenShift? What are you storing on the file system?

Comment: Uhm, Im using a web service to create a file (shell script) inside cron job directory. Hence I have to find a way to the user who request create a new file on cron job directory always use the gear that contains cron job.

Comment: Why does the user always need to go back to that gear? Does the cron job write something to the file system that the user needs to be able to access later?

Comment: Once the file is written, the user don't need access again. The file(shell script) just execute an internal task. As I said, if the file is written on a  different gear that contains cron job cartridge the task is never executed. Because not all gears have cron job cartridge, or it is posible set cron jobs cartridge on all gears?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like amazon s3 to store your files, then they will be accessible to all of the gears in your scaled application.You would need to use an amazon s3 access library that is available for your language.  If you are using Ruby on Rails, I would suggest using Paperclip.

I don't believe that you will be able to modify the haproxy configuration enough to always send a specific user to a specific gear within your application, and that also is a really bad programming practice to get in the habit of...

Comment: thanks for reply. And what about and specific URL always go to specific gear. I add additional info to my question.